# java quicksort with duplicates

Tags: java, duplicates, quicksort

I'm trying to implement quicksort, and the following algo works for an array with all unique values (e.g. { 3, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 9, 4 } ), but not for an array with duplicate values (e.g. { 3, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 9, 5, 4 } ).

I understand why the algo is failing: because the two pointers i and j never get incremented, and so when point to duplicate values, the conditions arr[i] < pivot and arr[j] > pivot never get met, and the code gets stuck in an infinite loop trying to swap those values over and over. I also understand that putting i++ and j-- after the swap line solves this problem, and correctly sorts the array in the end. But I don't understand why.

I've been studying quicksort so much, and I think the general concept is that after each iteration of sorting the array / subarray, the pivot ends up in it's "final" sorted position. When I add the i++ and j-- lines to this algo, that isn't true anymore; each iteration ends with the pivot not necessarily in its final position, so it doesn't make sense to sort the left and right subarrays assuming that the pivot position is already correct.

Can someone explain what is wrong with my code, or what is wrong with my understanding with the algo? Thank you!

```
public void quickSort(int[] arr) {

    quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
}

public void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {

    System.out.print("before: ");
    printArr(arr);

    if ( ((high - low) + 1) < 2) //as long as the subarray length not equal to 0 or 1
        return;

    int pivot = arr[low];
    int i = low;
    int j = high;

    System.out.println("pivot = " + pivot + ", low = " + low + ", high = " + high);

    while(i < j) {
        while(arr[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }

        while(arr[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        if(i < j) {
            swap(arr, i, j);
        }
    }

    System.out.print("after: ");
    printArr(arr);

    quickSort(arr, low, i-1);
    quickSort(arr, j+1, high);
}

public void swap(int arr[], int i, int j) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

public void printArr(int[] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Wikipedia has an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements) with a section discussing repeated elements which might help.

Comment: Either `<` has to be `<=` or `>` has to be `>=`, but not both.  This is true for pretty much every sort.  You have to make a decision to treat the `==` case as either `<` or `>`.

Comment: @AndrewS my problem is not that it takes a long time, but that it takes forever. I think it is an issue with the logic of my code, but I don't know what the issue is. Do you have any insight?